How can I retrigger the toast notification every time the server action is called?
In my client I have:
const [error, loginUser, pending] = useActionState(login, null);

loginUser gets called from a login form:
<form action={loginUser}>....</form>
error keeps track of the error returned and if not-null then it shows a toast notification:
 useEffect(() => {
   // this will only fire if the error changes ;(
   error && toast.error(error);
}, [error]);


This works the first time a user encounters an error (like the password is too short, but it could be anything etc). But, if the user tries again and encounters the same error then no new toast is shown...but it should even though it is the same error message. Although this is my login page I need the same functionality for my registration page.
I've tried the following:
let [error, register, pending] = useActionState(registerUser, null);
useEffect(() => {
   // this will only fire if the error changes ;(
   error && toast.error(error);
   error = null; // reset the error so it triggers useEffect() again..still doesn't work ;(
}, [error]);


But, sadly, this still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Your error is a string, which is primitive. And of course the useEffect will not be triggered if it's the same error.
Your login needs to return an object, and its structure should be
{
   id: Math.random(),
   message: 'some error message string'
}

 useEffect(() => {
   error && toast.error(error.message);
}, [error]);


It should work. Try it.
